# What is Smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

To my knowledge ,a smart contract is a program code that can be deployed into the ethereum blockchain.But i need to know more about smart contracts.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Click here: [Smart contracts](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Ethereum%20smart%20contracts)
The first few results will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contract is a term used to describe computer program code that is capable of facilitating, executing, and enforcing the negotiation or performance of an agreement (i.e. contract) using blockchain technology. The entire process is automated can act as a complement, or substitute, for legal contracts, where the terms of the smart contract are recorded in a computer language as a set of instructions.